# Transform an array into a string with adding numbers of each element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
function arrayTransform(array) {
  if (array.lengths === 0) {
    console.log("Empty")
  } else {
    console.log(array.join());
  }
}

arrayTransform(array);
```

the outcome should be 1.a, 2.b, 3.c
I am getting abc

Comment: What is it in your code that you expect to prepend the numeric values to each array element?

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates a number...

Comment: array.map(function(e, i){return (i+1) + '.' + e}).join()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you wnat to add the index with the element. In that case use `map` function which will return an array and then use `join` to create the final string

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function arrayTransform(array) {
  if (array.lengths === 0) {
    console.log("Empty")
  } else {
    return array.map((item, index) => {
      return `${index+1}.${item}` // template literals

    }).join()
  }
}

console.log(arrayTransform(array));
```

Comment: Hey, just a quick question for me to better understand. Why did you put join outside of else statement? Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

You could map the incremented index with the value and join it to the wanted style.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
function arrayTransform(array) {
  if (array.lengths === 0) {
    console.log("Empty")
  } else {
    console.log(array.map((v, i) => [i + 1, v].join('.')).join());
  }
}

arrayTransform(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` to get the resultant string:

```js
let data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let reducer = arr => arr.length ?
                     arr.reduce((r, c, i) => (r.push(`${i + 1}.${c}`), r), []).join() :
                     'Empty';

console.log(reducer(data));
console.log(reducer([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Would you mind using the ES6 solution as shared below. Let me know if you need it in ES5.

```
let result = array.map((val, i) => i + 1 + "." + val);
console.log(result);
```